# No more tagged Photos with facebook Graph

Tags: php, facebook, graph, facebook-graph-api

I have this problem since few weeks, after the last facebook changes in Graph API (the required access_token).

When I retrieve the tagged elements from a fan page I only get "statuses" and no photos.
I'm sure there are tagged picture in this page because I can see them on the wall and also, because it worked until few weeks ago.

I'm using the php SDK:

```
$obj=$facebook->api("/PAGEID/tagged/?access_token=".$access_token);
```

When I analize the $obj, there are only "status" values!

Did I forget something or it's a facebook bug?